# Updating firestore array of maps shows error : Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arrayobject

i have a document in firestore like below

[image]

what i want to do is update this fields time and stage 
i tried these with update and set methods

```
db.collection("record").doc("user"+user).collection("datas").doc("roadmap").update({
  first:[{
  0:[ stage:"new stage",
    time:"new time,
    done:false
  }]
  }]
  })
```

and

```
db.collection("startups").doc("user"+user).collection("datas").doc("roadmap").update({
  first:{[ 
     stage:"new stage",
    time:"new time",
    done:false
  }]
  })
```

but it always shows error such as :**[![`FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined`]**

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
db.collection("record").doc("user"+user).collection("datas").doc("roadmap")
.update({ first: [{ stage: 'new stage', time: 'new time', done: false }] });
```

This will work because your array has only one element (a map).

Note that if you want to modify one specific element of an array with several elements, you will need to first read the array in your front-end, modify the array and then write back the modified array to Firestore.

---

Even if it is not what you are looking for, it's worth noting the `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` methods, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) for more details.